# System Settings window can not be maximised

Tags: settings

The System Settings Window is the only window, that can't be maximised. Is this a known bug, or did I possibly break something?

Comment: I think you must have broken something, my System Settings window maximizes as it should.

Comment: how you are trying to maximize , by clicking  arrow at top right corner? try this : `hold and drag ` the window to maximize or minimize ,Is it working ?..

Comment: no. this doesn't help
I have elementary in virtualbox on another machine and it is the same problem over there.
The only idea which might have broken this, might be installing elementary-tweaks.

Comment: Did you try maximizing it with the default keyboard shortcut? It's `super + arrow up`

Comment: Yes, that also doesn't work

Comment: Do you have something installed that potentially modifies the system settings and/or its entries? Some applications like Elementary Tweaks add entries, as does Numix Folders. Double check this, maybe give it a try without one of these if they're present.

Answer (score 1):

The System Settings window can be maximized, unmaximized, and resized.

There are two arrows on the top right (or at least there should be). Click these to maximize and unmaximize the window. If these do not work try a different method.

Use the keyboard shortcut of (Windows Key + Up Arrow).

Answer (score 0):

Its elementary-tweaks.
I faced a similar problem while trying to maximise the settings app but when I uninstalled tweaks, it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with
`sudo apt remove elementary-tweaks`

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated Let me inform you that we love informative answers with step by step guide. Please try to post detailed information so that it is simple enough for someone with zero technical knowledge to easily understand.